# RSA Digital Signature System is failing for larger Prime numbers

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature

I implemented RSA cryptosystem to create a simple digital signature system. It is for freeCodeCamp's upcoming Cryptography curriculum.

The below program logs "Failure" when I use some bigger prime numbers like p = 11, q = 17. I am hashing my message and the result is smaller than N. I don't know why this is happening. Please guide me in the right direction.

This is for teaching millions of people out there. If you have any suggestions for improvement on the current implementation then please feel free to comment :)

Git Repo: https://github.com/vkweb/digital-signature-system

Thanks! Happy coding <3

````
const firstPrime =11;
const secondPrime = 19;
const N = firstPrime * secondPrime;
const phiOfN = (firstPrime - 1) * (secondPrime - 1);
let publicKey = 0;

function hashTheMessage(message) {
  let hashValue = 0;
  for (let i = 0, msgLength = message.length; i < msgLength; ++i) {
    hashValue += message.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return hashValue % N === 0 ? 1 : hashValue % N;
}

function isCoPrime(smallerNum, largerNum) {
  for (let i = 2; i <= smallerNum; ++i) {
    if (smallerNum % i === 0 && largerNum % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function generatePrivateKey() {
  for (let i = 2; i < phiOfN; ++i) {
    if (isCoPrime(i, N) && isCoPrime(i, phiOfN)) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  console.log("\nPrivate key can't be generated.");
  return 0;
}

function generatePublicKey(privateKey) {
  if (!privateKey) {
    console.log("\nPublic key can't be generated.");
  } else {
    publicKey = 1;
    while (privateKey) {
      if ((publicKey * privateKey) % phiOfN === 1 && privateKey !== publicKey) {
        return;
      }
      publicKey += 1;
    }
  }
}

function generateSignature(hashValue, privateKey) {
  return Math.pow(hashValue, privateKey) % N;
}

function decryptSignature(digitalSignature) {
  return Math.pow(digitalSignature, publicKey) % N;
}

let hashValue = hashTheMessage("Hello world!");
let privateKey = generatePrivateKey();
generatePublicKey(privateKey);
let signature = generateSignature(hashValue, privateKey);
let decryptedSignature = decryptSignature(signature);

if(decryptedSignature === hashValue)
{
  console.log("Success!");
}
else
{
  console.log("Failure!");
}
```
````

Comment: Perhaps the computation Math.pow(digitalSignature, publicKey) % N is overflowing internally...

Comment: Is there a way to check the overflow? 

I am new to the JavaScript world.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Programming questions are off-topic here, even if they are about cryptography. Programming questions belong on stackoverflow; I can migrate this there for you.

Comment: @poncho You were right. (Math.pow) is overflowing. Thanks. I've fixed it now.

Comment: If you're teaching RSA then it is important to use a big integer implementation with a modPow method, even if your examples only use smallish numbers. This is especially true in Javascript with its gormless "number" type that is nothing but a trap for unsuspecting beginners. The extra baggage of having to use methods like "multiply" for seemingly simple arithmetic operations is actually a benefit for learning RSA crypto.

Comment: @JamesKPolk+ note Javascript-now-ECMAscript just recently added support for BigInt; according to Mozilla site it is available in Chrome and nodejs about a year and Firefox at 68 (to be released soon), but not not IE and Edge (although Edge supposedly now is chromium?) and Safari. But for sizes that are secure, repeated mulmod by itself, although correct, won't complete before Earth is destroyed; you need at least square-and-multiply and probably windowing and CRT, and without additional precaution you are still vulnerable to sidechannel attacks. ...

Comment: ... Plus that hash and keygeneration are totally insecure and can be broken by any competent adversary in seconds (even at secure sizes). Those parts I think _would_ have been valid on crypto.SX.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I never mentioned "mulmod", I wrote "modPow".

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, JamesKPolk

Check out the PR with the latest commits: https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/CurriculumExpansion/pull/184/files

I'm using BigInt for decryption. The hash function is not a cryptographic one. It's just for teaching the fundamentals of hashing. 

It would be great to see both of your suggestions on improving the learning experience of campers. Once it goes live, it'll hit millions of learners each month.